# Count Value based on condition, results are not correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Query returns 128 rows for court=MA, so the `MAFiledDaily` count should be 128.

The result is not correct.

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

```
SELECT 
    dbo.tblCourtRec.CourtLtrsCurr as [Court],
    dbo.tblSentences.CaseNo as [CaseNo],
    dbo.tblSentences.DispDate as [DispDate],
    dbo.tblSentences.DispDate as [DispMethod],
    -- Get totals by Court
    (SELECT count(caseno) 
     FROM dbo.tblCaseFiling 
     WHERE filedate = CASE 
                         WHEN datepart(weekday, getdate()) = 2 
                           THEN datediff(day, 3, getdate()) 
                         ELSE datediff(day, 1, getdate()) 
                      END 
       AND tblcourtrec.CourtLtrsCurr = 'MA') AS MAFiledDaily
FROM 
    [MF_COURT].[dbo].[tblSentences]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblCourtRec ON dbo.tblCourtRec.CaseNo = dbo.tblSentences.CaseNo
WHERE
    dbo.tblCourtRec.CourtLtrsCurr = 'MA'
    AND YEAR(dbo.tblSentences.DispDate) = YEAR(getdate()) 
    AND MONTH(dbo.tblSentences.DispDate) = MONTH(getdate())
ORDER BY
    dbo.tblCourtRec.CourtLtrsCurr
```

Sample data:

```
Court   CaseNo  DispDate        DispMethod  MAFiledDaily
MA      M1004861    01/05/2015  DISM        269
MA      M1354445    01/05/2015  REVW        269
MA      M1354445    01/05/2015  DISM        269
MA      M1363238    01/05/2015  DISM        269
MA      M1365908    01/05/2015  NAOG        269
```

Comment: Can you set-up a sql fidle?  Or atleast the rest of the sql?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the entirety of the first query.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER

Here's your subquery (reformatted a little, just to help me understand it better):

```
-- Get totals by Court
(select count(caseno) 
 from   dbo.tblCaseFiling 
 where  filedate = CASE 
         WHEN datepart(weekday,getdate())= 2 
         THEN datediff(day,3,getdate()) 
         ELSE datediff(day,1,getdate()) 
       END  
  and tblcourtrec.CourtLtrsCurr = 'MA'
 )
```

Assuming your `filedate` comparison is correct, I think the problem is still that you are referencing a table outside of your subquery, but not in a way that limits the records you retrieve in the subquery.

Your outer query references the table `tblCourtRec` and limits records returned to those where `dbo.tblCourtRec.CourtLtrsCurr ='MA'`.

Your subquery is also referencing `tblCourtRec` - but it's referring to the value in the outer query. There's no link in your subquery between the records you're returning and the specific record in the outer query.  You do *refer* to the record in the outer query, but you aren't connecting it to `tblCaseFiling` in any way.

Assuming that `tblCaseFiling` has some data in it that indicates what state the filing was in, you'd need a clause like this:

```
 where [file date comparison]
 and   tblCaseFiling.CourtFiledIn = 'MA'
```

... or like this (which would be what's called a correlated subquery):

```
 where [file date comparison]
 and   tblCaseFiling.CourtFiledIn = tblCourtRec.CourtLtrsCurr
```

Comment: Ann, thanks for your post. I updated my post with "Cleaner" code.